# youtube subscription button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have added this code

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UClaHcVK3_3vgPZHzYuaLPdQ" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```

to my website to embed a subscribe button there. I have also added

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

to the header. but when user clicks on the button he gets a Network Error like the following

> `"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - https://www.youtube.com/subscription_ajax?action_create_subscription_to_channel=1&c=UClaHcVK3_3vgPZHzYuaLPdQ&eurl=http%3A%2F%2Fexclusivesurgery.com%2F"`

could you please tell me how i can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> YouTube Subscribe Button
>
> The YouTube Subscribe Button lets you add a one-click Subscribe button
>   to any page. The button lets people subscribe to your YouTube channel
>   without having to leave your site to either log in to YouTube or
>   confirm their subscriptions.
>
> To add a button, your application needs to load this JavaScript file:

`https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js`

> You can add a button by using
>   an element, such as a `<div>`, that sets its class to `g-ytsubscribe` and
>   uses other attributes to customize the button. The code below shows a
>   simple integration that displays a Subscribe button for the
>   GoogleDevelopers channel.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script> <div
class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="UClaHcVK3_3vgPZHzYuaLPdQ"></div>



<script>
  function onYtEvent(payload) {
    var logElement = document.getElementById('ytsubscribe-events-log');
    if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
      logElement.innerHTML = 'You will love this channel! :D'
    } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
      logElement.innerHTML = 'We are sorry you are unsubscribing. :('
    }
    if (window.console) {
      window.console.log('ytsubscribe event: ', payload);
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="UClaHcVK3_3vgPZHzYuaLPdQ" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
        <div id="ytsubscribe-events-log"></div>
```

Take at https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button to generate the proper button code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix this until Google fixes it themselves.